# Storing JSON API data into Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, api

I have managed to obtain JSON data from API and I am trying to store it in a Python dictionary. I have followed a few tutorials and other stack overflow guides but does not seem to help.

Comment: do you want same output in dictionary object?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `json.loads(response.text)`

Comment: @Sharvin Use this json.loads(response.text)

Comment: Any help regarding organizing the data will also be great 

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: post the complete json related to your expected output

Comment: I have updated it @deadshot

Comment: looks like there is no difference between you input and expected output? can you elaborate more what exactly your requirement?

Comment: @deadshot I am required to make the output when I run my codes to look as the expected output with categories like file information, app information and so on.

Comment: @Sharvin do you want the output as nested dictionary or separated dictionary for each category and does the keys same for all inputs or it will change with input?

Comment: @deadshot I had nested dictionary in my mind but I don't mind having separate as well and the keys will most likely change with different inputs.

Comment: if the keys changes with input how to identify which key is related to which category?

Comment: True @deadshot , that was the issue I was facing when having the categorization in my planning. As for now, I am required to focus only on this one input so the key will remain same.

Comment: if the keys is fixed create a list with keys for each category then you can create the dictionary

Comment: I see. So it'll be something like this? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-initialize-a-dictionary-with-only-keys-from-a-list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API response return JSON object you can try

```
response.json()
```

and you will get a dictionary of a JSON object returned by the API.

Elsewhere you if the `response.text` is returning a JOSN object as string you can use the `json` package to load the string as a dictionary by `json.loads()` method as

```
json.loads(response.text).
```

Comment: It works, thank you. What about sorting the output into categories. For example, the version and title to be categorized as part 1 while file_name, app_name and app_type to be categorized as part 2. In order to make the output more readable and organized as it is just a long line of data right now.

Comment: There is a need for a dictionary that has the key of part number and  value of the desired keys from the JSON object.

Comment: How do I achieve that? I have added an expected output in my question too.

Comment: The response and the expected outputted are not the same the have different keys